# How can i get the module list of a remote 64 bit process from a 32 bit app in Windows?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I want to find the module name (dll/exe names) and their start address, size, on a remote process.

The problem is that when i use `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` with `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32` or `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE`, i get this error:

```
Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.
```

So my question is, what is the best solution, other than compiling to 64 bit or injecting a dll, to solve this problem? (That works from XP and above, not just 7+)

Comment: The linked duplicate question has nothing to do with this question..... this happens before the call to process32first.. and the answer there doesnt apply here.

Comment: Without a [mcve] we are left to guess. Maybe this guess was wrong or maybe not. There's nothing in the question itself that would allow us to determine this. See [ask].

Comment: you can not do this from 32bit code. you need have 64bit code for query 64bit modules

Comment: @IInspectable Its pretty obvious from the question that this is happening because I'm 32 bit and the remote is 64 bit.. Just wanted to see if there is any workaround

Comment: @RbMm So there is absolutely nothing i can do to workaround it?

Comment: That's not what the comment says. The obvious workaround is launching a 64-bit process that does the enumeration and communicates through one of the available [IPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications) channels.

Comment: almost. possible have 64bit (shell) code in your 32bit binary and enter to 64bit mode direct from your 32bit process. here you can call only ntdll api (and need resolve it import before call). call `LdrQueryProcessModuleInformation` do task, but need have very strong knowledge and experience for do this.

Comment: @RbMm i actually thought about that dirty trick of switching to 64 bit from 32 bit app, but can't remember how compatible was it? Because i need this to work on 64 bit versions of XP+, so is the trick compatible in this regard?

Comment: yes, possible write correct code wthis will be work on any 64 windows (no xp 64 - 64 begin from 2003). but what sense do this ? much more simply in all sense write 64 bit module

Comment: @RbMm unfortunately my app needs to stay 32 bit.

Comment: Your program doesn't need to be compiled for x64 to launch a 64-bit process. Your program doesn't need to be compiled for x64 to contain a binary resource of a 64-bit PE image.

Comment: @IInspectable surprisingly yes, but for enumerate modules in 64bit process..

Comment: @IInspectable Yes i assume one other way is to just drop a 64 bit compiled binary and execute that, which makes sense.

Comment: @RbMm another idea: parse PEB of remote process?

Comment: @OneAndOnly - PEB will be in address higer than 0xFFFFFFFF. how you read it data in this case ?

Comment: @RbMm So no way i can make ReadProcessMemory work in this case?

Comment: of course no. how you pass 64bit address to it ? exist NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64. but better have 64bit code